# Sort not identical lists Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have two lists.

One list contains only codes e.g.:

```
b3b
3cd
6f6
4d8
96b
00a
774
eb3
607
7e5
```

The other list contains code with names e.g.

```
b3b:John
607:Eric
7e5:Jarrold
```

But the list is not compleet yet.

What I want as output, because the other cannot be removed and has to be in the right order, e.g.

```
b3b:John
3cd
6f6
4d8
96b
00a
774
eb3
607:Eric
7e5:Jarrold
```

Already have this code but it only returns True or False but that's not what I want.

```
list1 = [line.strip() for line in open('list1')]
list2 = [line.strip() for line in open('list2')]

comp = [i[:3] for i in list2]

for i in list1:
    print(i, i in list2)
```

Maybe anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: Is that second list just a list of strings?

Comment: I have two text files that I open. The order of text file cannot be changed and only contains the user codes. Text file two is user code with name. And it seem to be loaded in a array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a dictionary mapping keys to names instead of a list as the second data structure:

```
with open("list1") as f:
    keys = [line.strip() for line in f]
with open("list2") as f:
    names = dict(line.strip().split(":", 1) for line in f)
```

Now you can efficiently implement your loop:

```
for k in keys:
    print(k, names.get(k, ""))
```

Performing a linear search in `list2` for every entry of `list1` would be rather inefficient.  Apart from the better performance, a dictionary is also a better model of the meaning of your data.